# Error : Could not find the main class: org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI

Tags: java, php, solr, lucene

When I starting solr-5.1.0 in Ubuntu by,

```
/bin/var/www/solr-5.0.0/bin ./solr start
```

I get an error as below,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/solr/util/SolrCLI : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)

Could not find the main class: org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI. Program will exit.

SolrCloud example running, please visit http://localhost:8983/solr
```

But I have found solution to upgrade java to 1.7 or above. I have installed 1.8 version. But till now I got an error.

What to do? Help me in this please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue of version 51 is for the not having java 7...
it might be the issue that you have installed/upgraded java but did not set
it to JAVA_HOME & PATH.

Install the java 7 and set java home to it. It would resolve your issue.
Please make sure that both JAVA_HOME and PATH environment variables are updated to 7...

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_75
```

Note : When using Oracle Java 7 or OpenJDK 7, be sure to not use the GA build 147 or update versions u40, u45 and u51! We recommend using u55 or later.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Actually I can install it on windows but not in this. Have a great day !!